# Why char value copy won't work in OS X?

Tags: c

It's a textbook C code

```
void strcpy_new(char *s, char *t) {
    while ((*s = *t) != '\0') {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    char *s = "this is line a";
    char *t = "this is line b";
    printf("%s", s);
    strcpy_new(s, t);
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run it with Xcode, I got EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Show how you call `strcpy_new`

Comment: I edited my question with complete code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is because those string literals `"this is line a"` and `"this is line b"` are stored in read-only memory. Attempting to write to it (`*s = *t`) is undefined behavior and you are receiving a crash because of it.

To remedy this code you should allocate some memory for `s` so that it is large enough to hold the second string (`t`):

```
    char s[] = "this is line a"; // contrived example, s and t are the same length
    char *t = "this is line b";
    strcpy_new(s, t);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet that you're trying to run `strcpy_new` with a destination `char *s` that is a string literal

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a = "Some String";
    char *b = "Another string";
    strcpy(b, a);
    return 0;
}
```

will give an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.  The following, however, won't

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a = "Some String";
    char b[] = "Another string";
    strcpy(b, a);
    return 0;
}
```

The difference is that in the first case, `b` points to a block of memory in the `__TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals` section of the executable, which is write protected.  In the second case, it points to a block of memory on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the effect of overwriting a string literal is undefined.

```
char *s = "this is line a";
char *t = "this is line b";
strcpy_new(s, t);
```

`s` and `t` are both off in the data section of the code, and your particular setup happens to give you an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` when you try changing them.

Answer (score 1):

String literal are read-only. A good answer is found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=357869

String literals in C are read-only. In your sample code, "My string" is a string literal.

The str[] declaration copies the literal into writable memory (stack or heap). Therefore, your program can modify the string.

The * declaration initializes a pointer to the literal itself, so you have a pointer to a read-only segment. If you try to overwrite it, you get the SEGV.